# Use ion-grid to have a duolingo-ish style

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm wondering how I could build a layout that would look like Duolingo's interface. I have an array that contains what buttons should be displayed, and they should be arranged in pairs, and in the case of an odd element, it should be centralized.

But I haven't figure out how I could make such interface. Is there any way of making it? The way I'm building it, so far, I only put a single item in each row.

HTML:

```
<ion-grid>
    <div *ngFor="let button of pillars; let i = index;">
      <ion-row *ngIf="button.ref == 'pillar'">
        <ion-col>
          <btn-rounded-picture [text]="button.name" [imageURL]="'/assets/assess/' + button.name + '.png'" (click)="detailPillar(button)"></btn-rounded-picture>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </div>
  </ion-grid>
```

And this is how I expect it to be like:

[image: Expected layout]

Answer (score 0):

If they're static buttons, do you know how many they are? If so you can try a for inside for like this:

YOUR .TS FILE

```
obj: any[] = [
    [
        { icon: 'star', button: 'bla' },
        { icon: 'trash', button: 'bla' }
    ],
    [
        { icon: 'eye', button: 'bla' }
    ],
    [
        { icon: 'star', button: 'bla' },
        { icon: 'eye', button: 'bla' },
        { icon: 'trash', button: 'bla' }
    ]
];
```

YOUR HTML FILE

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row *ngFor="let row of obj; let i = index">
    <ion-col *ngFor="let col of obj[i]" text-center>
      <ion-icon name="{{col.icon}}"></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: no, I don't know how many of them I will display, as the application uses a JSON to check what buttons should be loaded. So it depends on what JSON version I'm using. There's a filter `*ngIf="button.ref == 'pillar'"` that specifies what pillars (the buttons) should be loaded. They come in a single array, that might be not hepful to do the way I want :/